# How to insert a line into the middle of an existing file

Tags: perl

> consider an example where i want to insert few lines of text when
>       particular patter matches(if **$line=~m/few lines in here/** then
>       insert lines in next line):
>
> ```
> *current file:*
>
> "This is my file and i wanna insert few lines in here  and other
> text of the file will continue."
>
> *After insertion:*
>
> "This is my file and i wanna insert few lines in here  this is my
> new text which i wanted to insert and other text of the file will
> continue."
> ```

This is my code:

```
my $sourcename = $ARGV[1];
my $destname = $ARGV[0];
print $sourcename,"\n";
print $destname,"\n";
my $source_excel = new Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;  
my $source_book = $source_excel->Parse($sourcename) or die "Could not open source Excel file $sourcename: $!";

my $source_cell;
#Sheet 1 - source sheet page having testnumber and worksheet number
my $source_sheet = $source_book->{Worksheet}[0];            #It is used to access worksheet

$source_cell = $source_sheet->{Cells}[1][0];                #Reads content of the cell;
my $seleniumHost = $source_cell->Value; 
print $seleniumHost,"\n";

open (F, '+>>',"$destname") or die "Couldn't open `$destname': $!";
my $line;

while ($line = <F>){
print $line;
if($line=~m/FTP/){
#next if /FTP/;
print $line;
print F $seleniumHost;}
```

Comment: Maybe you can tell us more about what you're trying to accomplish?  Just how big is this file and what's in it?  Do you have control over the format?

Comment: There are a lot of ways to accomplish what is shown, but what do you need exactly?  How do you identify the location to insert text?  Does it need to be formatted as shown?  Maybe you should be clearer in your request.  Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The perlfaq covers this.  [How do I change, delete, or insert a line in a file, or append to the beginning of a file?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-change,-delete,-or-insert-a-line-in-a-file,-or-append-to-the-beginning-of-a-file?)

Files are fixed blocks of data. They behave much like a piece of paper.  How do you insert a line into the middle of a piece of paper?  You can't, not unless you left space.  You must recopy the whole thing, inserting your line into the new copy.

Comment: i would like to insert in the midle of the file(i dont wanna over write) but perlfaq suggesting to create another file and write there.

Comment: @Sirga: Even your existing code gives the impression that you intend to have a different source and destination file.  But if you would like a simple way to do it, have a look at Tie::File.  There are other, possibly more efficient methods, but it's hard to beat the simplicity of Tie::File.

Comment: @DavidO: I wanted to do following things. 1)read data from excel file. 2)Open a text file and search for a pattern if it matches then write data(read from excel) into next line without overwriting.

Comment: @sirga You must, at some point, rewrite the file from the point of insert forward.  See the paper analogy above.  It's just how files work.  You probably want some sort of database which can handle searches and inserts.  SQLite or even BerkeleyDB are light and easy.

Answer (score 3):

In a perl one-liner :

```
perl -ane 's/few lines in here  and other\n/this is my\nnew text which i wanted to insert and other /; s/continue./\ncontinue./; print ' FILE
```

If you don't want a one-liner, it's easy to takes the substitutions in any script ;)

Comment: Thanx for the replay but i dont want to replace text instead i would like to insert lines of text in next line without overwriting any text. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you know the line:

```
perl -ne 'if ($. == 8) {s//THIS IS NEW!!!\n/}; print;'
```

Obviously you'd have to use -i to make the actual changes
OR:

```
perl -i -pe 'if($. == 8) {s//THIS IS NEW!!!\n/}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone mentioned Tie::File, which is a solution I'll have to look at for editing a file, but I generally use File::Slurp, which has relatively recently added edit_file and edit_file_lines subs.

Comment: but can we do proper error handling with File::Slurp?

Answer (score 0):

Using perl's in-place edit flag (-i), it's easy to add lines to an existing file using Perl, as long as you can key off a text string, such as (in your case) "wanna insert few lines in here":

```
perl -pi -e 's{wanna insert few lines in here}{wanna insert few lines in here  this is my\nnew text which i wanted to insert }' filename
```

It overwrites your old sentence (don't be scared) with a copy of your old sentence (nothing lost) plus the new stuff you want injected.  You can even create a backup of the original file if you wish by passing a ".backup" extension to the -i flag:

```
perl -p -i'.backup' -e 's{wanna insert few lines in here}{wanna insert few lines in here  this is my\nnew text which i wanted to insert }' filename
```

More info on Perl's search & replace capabilities can be found here:

http://www.atrixnet.com/in-line-search-and-replace-in-files-with-real-perl-regular-expressions/

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid having to repeat the "markup" text using variable substitution.

```perl
echo -e "first line\nthird line" | perl -pe 's/(^first line$)/\1\nsecond line/'
```